# jupyter kernel restarting issue

Tags: kernel, jupyter, restart

i get this message when i run the jupyter notebook "The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened."

```
 http://localhost:8888/?token=bc7dc2e3b31daedf0c88a9dc766aa8e74e7d03aba7934770
[I 16:13:18.114 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 16:13:24.226 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20171117161317 (::1) 13.01ms referer
=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/TensorFlow-Book-master/ch02_basics/Concept01_defining_tensors.ipynb
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\BDU\Enivronments\TensorFlow-Book-master\ch02_basics\types.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[I 16:13:24.594 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 8b5449c6-2f01-4546-9ceb-1f036b9443e5
[I 16:13:27.535 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\BDU\Enivronments\TensorFlow-Book-master\ch02_basics\types.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[I 16:13:30.541 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\BDU\Enivronments\TensorFlow-Book-master\ch02_basics\types.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[I 16:13:33.542 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\BDU\Enivronments\TensorFlow-Book-master\ch02_basics\types.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[W 16:13:34.667 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 8b5449c6-2f01-4546-9ceb-1f036b9443e5
[I 16:13:36.562 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 8b5449c6-2f01-4546-9ceb-1f036b9443e5 restarted
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "c:\users\bdu\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "C:\Users\BDU\Enivronments\TensorFlow-Book-master\ch02_basics\types.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[W 16:13:39.592 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 16:13:39.592 NotebookApp] Kernel 8b5449c6-2f01-4546-9ceb-1f036b9443e5 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 8b5449c6-2f01-4546-9ceb-1f036b9443e5 restarted failed!
[W 16:13:39.629 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/d1b11c7a-e718-4f3e-aaf4-ebd6b66e10ec (::1): Kernel deleted before se
ssion
[W 16:13:39.630 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 16:13:39.631 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/d1b11c7a-e718-4f3e-aaf4-ebd6b66e10ec (::1) 3.00ms referer=http://loc
alhost:8888/notebooks/TensorFlow-Book-master/ch02_basics/Concept01_defining_tensors.ipynb
```

please help me to resolve

Regards
Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you failed to import tensorflow:

> import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow'

So you should fix that first and install it.